# How do I view the output of a program loaded into MSP430?

Tags: encryption, output, aes, msp430

I have an AES encryption program that has been loaded into the MSP430 Launchpad. Is there any way I am able to view the output on the terminal to check whether the encryption works? I am using Ubuntu 16.04. This is what the terminal shows as I run the load and continue command in the terminal.

```
(gdb) load
Loading section .rodata, size 0x20e lma 0x4400
Loading section .rodata2, size 0xc lma 0x4610
Loading section .data, size 0x9e lma 0x461c
Loading section .upper.data, size 0x2 lma 0x46ba
Loading section .text, size 0x694 lma 0x46bc
Loading section __reset_vector, size 0x2 lma 0xfffe
Starting address 0x46bc, load size 2384
Transfer rate: 5KB/sec, 340 bytes/write.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
```

The MSP430 is connected through USB FET at ttyACM0. I have a .out file for encryption, but I have no idea how to show its output to check whether the encryption is working.

This is the .c file that I used.

```
#include "msp430x26x.h"
#include "TI_aes.h"
int main( void )
{
unsigned char state[] = {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff};
//unsigned char ciphertext[] = {0x69, 0xc4, 0xe0, 0xd8, 0x6a, 0x7b, 0x04, 0x30, 0xd8, 0xcd, 0xb7, 0x80, 0x70, 0xb4, 0xc5, 0x5a};
unsigned char key[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f};

aes_encrypt(state, key);
//aes_decrypt(state, key);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A microcontroller does not have a terminal. What exactly do you mean with "output"? Are you printing something through a UART?

Comment: @CL. I am using msp430gcc to load the program into the MSP430, I am not using UART. How do I print the output through mspgcc?

Comment: What output? How does your program try to output anything?

Comment: @CL. I've added the .c file I used to make the .out file, is there something missing in my code to show any form of output?

Comment: The function `aes_encrypt()` encrypts a single 128-bit block in place. If you have a debugger, you can look at the variable; otherwise, your program must output the data to somewhere.

Comment: @CL. Alright so how and where should I output the program to?

Comment: That depends. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I personally use msp430-elf-run (part of the msp430-gcc toolchain) to debug and view any debug messages on console before deploying on the actual hardware itself.